# subset data.frame union multiple intervals

Tags: r

Consider the following `data.frame`,

```
d <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 10, length=100), value = rnorm(100))
```

I wish to subset based on `x` belonging to any of the following intervals,

```
intervals <- list(c(0.2, 0.8), c(1, 2), c(8, 8.2))

test <- function(range, x){
  which(x >= range[1] & x <= range[2])
}

d[Reduce(`union`, lapply(intervals, test, x=d$x)), ]
```

Now, the testing function seems redundant, as it looks an awful lot like the built-in `findInterval`, but I cannot find an elegant way to use it.

```
condition <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(lapply(intervals,  findInterval,
                                       x=d$x, all.inside=FALSE), `==`, 1))

d[condition, ]
```

Can you suggest better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d[unlist(sapply(intervals, function(x) which(!is.na(cut(d$x,x))))),]
           x       value
3  0.2020202  0.15488314
4  0.3030303 -0.06891842
5  0.4040404  1.59909655
6  0.5050505  0.31006866
7  0.6060606  1.68986821
8  0.7070707  0.18500635
11 1.0101010  0.18721091
12 1.1111111  0.32485063
13 1.2121212 -0.42728405
14 1.3131313  0.84220081
15 1.4141414 -1.30745237
16 1.5151515 -1.90335389
17 1.6161616 -0.47139683
18 1.7171717  0.01622827
19 1.8181818  0.76362918
20 1.9191919 -0.37827765
81 8.0808081  0.46672521
82 8.1818182  1.27038641
```

Edit: The same result using `findInterval`

```
d[findInterval(d$x,unlist(intervals))%%2==1,]
```

Comment: @baptiste OK, added a `findInterval` solution

Comment: nice, it also removes the need for the `for` loop in `Reduce`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the `intervals` package.

```
d <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 10, length=100), value = rnorm(100))
intervals <- list(c(0.2, 0.8), c(1, 2), c(8, 8.2))
library(intervals)
intervals <- Intervals( do.call( rbind, intervals ) )
intervals <- reduce( intervals )  # Simplify, if they overlap
condition <- distance_to_nearest(d$x, intervals) == 0
# The following would allow for non-closed intervals,
# but it is awfully slow.
condition <- sapply( d$x, function(u) 
  any(!empty(interval_intersection( Intervals(c(u,u)), intervals ))))
d[condition,]
```

With `findInterval`, it may be trickier,
because it assumes the intervals are closed on one side and open on the other.
If this is acceptable, if the intervals are ordered and do not overlap, 
you just need to check if the interval number is odd.

```
intervals <- list(c(0.2, 0.8), c(1, 2), c(8, 8.2))
condition <- findInterval( d$x, unlist(intervals) ) %% 2 == 1
d[condition,]
```