# Remove rows in a dataframe containing values outside multiple intervals

Tags: r, dataframe, find, range, intervals

Been searching your forum for answers to my question witout results, the nearest I came was: [subset data.frame union multiple intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202578/subset-data-frame-union-multiple-intervals)! But I don't see how that can help me. Maybe my reading comprehension in english being to weak.

So, I have a data frame `study_a` containing 246 individuals, all given a specific code to entain anonymity. The code is one of 14 columns, the rest is answers on a questionnaire. An example:

```
"Code"
2
653
2678
3965
7342
4258
5245
```

My wish is to find those values outside the intervals 1-2999, 4251-4599 and 7000-7500 and in the end erase these rows (i.e individuals) since they are not supposed to be included in this study.

Except for the link I've also tried:

```
    in.interval.lo(study_a$"code", 1, 2999) #in.interval.lo(x, lo, hi)
```

But this function don't seem to work for multiple intervals. And furthermore, I get an error message when I try to specify which columns values I want to check (since there are 13 columns in addition to "code").

Thanks in advance for your help, and if this question already have been solved I would be most thankful for a link to it since I've failed in finding it.

Comment: Maybe `study_a[ !study_a$code %in% c(1:2999, 4251:4599, 7000:7500), ]` ?

Comment: Relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794414

Comment: possible match also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39977463/3871924

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at indexing in R using squared brackets and logicals. E.g.

```
study_a[(study_a$Code <= 2999) & (study_a$Code >= 4251),]
```

**Edit:**

Using `%in%`, and `!` NOT operator to negate the overlap:

```
study_a[ !study_a$code %in% c(1:2999, 4251:4599, 7000:7500), ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used the function above which resulted in;

Comment: <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
which I understood as there were no values/rows outside the given intervals?! Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: Use `str()` or `class()` to check if `study_a$Code` is numeric

Comment: changed it from factor to numeric, still tough generating the same result/message as above (<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) .

Answer (score 0):

Use subset function

```
xx <- c(1:2999, 4251:4599, 7000:7500)
study_a <- subset(study_a, !code %in% xx )
```